# how to solve FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-11 in android?

Tags: android

here is the code for exception::

```
if (getZoomLevel() != last_zoom)
 {
 // if computeScroll called before timer counts down we should drop it and start it over again
   zoom_event_delay_timer.cancel();
   zoom_event_delay_timer = new Timer();
   Log.v("last_zoom","last_zoom");
  zoom_event_delay_timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
  {
   @Override
  public void run()
  {
      zoom_change_listener.onZoomChange(_this, getZoomLevel(), last_zoom);
       Log.v("last_zoom","last_zoom"+last_zoom);
       last_zoom = getZoomLevel();
       Log.v("last_zoom","last_zoom");
   }
  }, events_timeout);
}
```

and the Error:

```
01-05 12:24:50.791: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11132): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-11
    01-05 12:24:50.791: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11132): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    01-05 12:24:50.791: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11132):     at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
    01-05 12:24:50.791: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11132):     at com.bluepal.android.parkable.Prakablescreen.onRegionChange(Prakablescreen.java:1028)
    01-05 12:24:50.791: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11132):     at com.bluepal.android.parkable.Prakablescreen$14.onPanChange(Prakablescreen.java:467)
    01-05 12:24:50.791: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11132):     at com.bluepal.android.parkable.EnhancedMapView$2.run(EnhancedMapView.java:126)
    01-05 12:24:50.791: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11132):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:289)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here seems to be that you are calling the UI thread from another thread (in this case the timer).
I found [these](https://web.archive.org/web/20201026071708/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2010/11/drawing-with-canvas-in-android-saving.html) [sites](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810154212/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html) for explanation and solving the problem (i used a handler).

Answer (score 1):

Please supply some source code .

From the error it seems that you are trying to modify an arraylist while iterating over it.If that is the case , use a temporary container for the arraylist & after all modifications, store  this temporary arraylist to your arraylist .

Answer (score 0):

> From the error it seems that you are
>   trying to modify an arraylist while
>   iterating over it

If 100rabh is right and you're not modifying your list though an iterator, maybe you can use a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html), which is ThreadSafe.